# Fill a column based on multiple columns' values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the  following dataframe

```
df
A    B    C    D
1    2    NA   3
2    3    NA   1
3    NA   1    2
```

A, B, C, and D are answers to a question. Basically, respondents ranked answers from 1 to 3 which means that one line cannot have 2 values the same. I am trying to make a new column which is a summary of the top 3 something such as.

```
1st    2nd    3rd
A      B      D
D      A      B
C      D      A
```

This format will make it easier for me to come up with conclusions such as, here are the 3rd top answers.

I didn't find any way to do this. Could you help me, please?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

One way is using [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) and indexing the columns:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.columns[df.values.argsort()[:,:-1]],
             columns=['1st', '2nd', '2rd'])

  1st 2nd 2rd
0   A   B   D
1   D   A   B
2   C   D   A
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `stack()/pivot()`:

```
(df.stack().astype(int)
   .reset_index(name='val')
   .pivot('level_0', 'val', 'level_1')
)
```

Output:

```
val      1  2  3
level_0         
0        A  B  D
1        D  A  B
2        C  D  A
```

Comment: What if I have other columns in my dataframe that I want to leave unchange?

Comment: You can either set those columns as index, or just run the script on the answer columns (e.g. `df[['A','B','C','D']].stack()...`)